# `pd.DateTimeIndex` is advised in backtesting.py library

Tags: python, back-testing

I am using the backtesting.py library https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/doc/backtesting/index.html

What is this error?
**UserWarning: Data index is not datetime. Assuming simple periods, but 'pd.DateTimeIndex' is advised. bt = Backtest(data, test2, cash=100000, commission=.002)**

```
import pandas as pd
from backtesting import Strategy
from backtesting import Backtest


data = pd.read_csv('I:/algotrading/BTCUSDT.csv')
data.columns = ['Time','Open','High','Low','Close'];


class test2(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        pass

    def next(self):
        # OHLC
        self.open = self.data.Open
        self.high = self.data.High
        self.low = self.data.Low
        self.close = self.data.Close

        if(self.close > self.open):
                self.position.close()
                self.buy()

        elif(self.close < self.open):
                self.position.close()
                self.sell()


bt = Backtest(data, test2, cash=100000, commission=.002)
stats = bt.run()
print(stats)
bt.plot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code required a **set_index**.

```
data = pd.read_csv('BTCUSDT.csv', index_col='Time', parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this fixed the issue for me

```py
data = pd.read_csv('BTCUSDT.csv')
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Data index is not datetime" suggests that the index of your data is not in a datetime format. The library, backtesting.py, that you are using requires the data index to be in a datetime format.

You can try these steps to solve the error you encountered:

- convert a string column to a datetime column by `pd.to_datetime()` function.
- Using `set_index()` function, that will help set index with converted datetime index.
  Here's an updated code snippet:

```
data = pd.read_csv('I:/algotrading/BTCUSDT.csv')
data.columns = ['Time','Open','High','Low','Close']
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])  # Convert the 'Time' column to datetime format
data = data.set_index('Time')  # Set the index
```